# Differences of pointers between unmanaged C++ and managed C++

Tags: windows, pointers, c++-cli, managed-c++

As the unmanaged C++ is feel free to locate to different object.
Such as the pointer to an array

```
int pt[50];
int* pointer = pt;
```

We can directly use *pointer to get the first value of the element in the array.
Thus, we can also use *(pointer++) in order to point to the second element.

However, if it is possible to directly use ^(pointer+5) to get the sixth element of the array?
The example is as follow.

```
array<int>^ pt = gcnew array<int>(50);
int^ pointer = pt;
```

How can I use the pointer as a medium to access different element in the array?

Answer (score 0):

here is a slightly different approach that may be of use ...

It uses interior pointer arithmetic  (to traverse an array).

Hope this helps.

```
using namespace System;

ref class Buf
{
    // ...
};

int main()
{
   array<Buf^>^ array_of_buf = gcnew array<Buf^>(10);

   // Create a Buf object for each array position
   for each (Buf^ bref in array_of_buf)
   {
      bref = gcnew Buf();
   }

   // create an interior pointer to elements of the array
   interior_ptr<Buf^> ptr_buf;

   // loop over the array with the interior pointer
   // using pointer arithmetic on the interior pointer
   for (ptr_buf = &array_of_buf[0]; ptr_buf <= &array_of_buf[9]; ptr_buf++)
   {
      // dereference the interior pointer with *
      Buf^ buf = *ptr_buf;
      // use the Buf class
   }
}
```

reference: C++/CLi the visual c++ language for .net (pg 99)

here is another example from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0fh545k.aspx

```
// interior_ptr.cpp
// compile with: /clr
using namespace System;

ref class MyClass {
public:
   int data;
};

int main() {
   MyClass ^ h_MyClass = gcnew MyClass;
   h_MyClass->data = 1;
   Console::WriteLine(h_MyClass->data);

   interior_ptr<int> p = &(h_MyClass->data);
   *p = 2;
   Console::WriteLine(h_MyClass->data);

   // alternatively
   interior_ptr<MyClass ^> p2 = &h_MyClass;
   (*p2)->data = 3;
   Console::WriteLine((*p2)->data);
}
```